# How to display a folder structure in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, markdown

What is the best way to show a folder structure using Stack Overflow formatting?

Here's how I have written it now, I wish I could do it better:

```
>_rels
>customXML
>docProps
>word //this folder contains most of the files that control the content of yhe document
    >_rels
         >document.xml.rels //this document tells word where the images are situated
    >media  //This folder contains all images embedded in the word
    >theme
    >document.xml //Is the actual content of the document
    >header1.xml //Is the content of the header
>[Content_Types].xml
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this (Using bullet list):

> - _rels
> - customXML
> - docProps
> - word //this folder contains most of the files that control the content of yhe document
>
>   - _rels
>
>     - document.xml.rels //this document tells word where the images are situated
>   - media  //This folder contains all images embedded in the word
>   - theme
>   - document.xml //Is the actual content of the document
>   - header1.xml //Is the content of the header
> - [Content_Types].xml